# Ever Heard of 4/0 Lights?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

An electrician I recently got a bid from made a number of recommendations involving installing what he called "Four-Oh" lights.  I wasn't sure I was hearing him right, so had him spell it out.  He told me there are great fixtures which are labelled "4/0" and that, with LED bulbs in them, they would work well for some of the lighting projects we discussed.

So, while out at the home improvement centers for other things, I took a peek in the light fixture aisle to see these 4/0 lights, but I did not see anything labeled that way.  The Internet shows nothing, either.  Has anyone else heard of these, or have I been sent on a snipe hunt?

Comment: @isherwood - Indeed; I noted this in my question, but I was hoping maybe I just have the search string wrong and someone might be able to tell me how to correctly type it.

Comment: @isherwood - I think he might have been talking about something like this, which fits in a 4/0 octagonal junction box:  http://www.amazon.com/Commercial-Electric-Recessed-White-Light/dp/B00BP0VVYI

Comment: Interesting. Recessed lighting without cans. Does that fit the context of your discussion?

Comment: @isherwood - I think it does.  I can't say for sure because he was making recommendations against my idea which involved using some LED strips in a closet.  He said these would give a more pleasing effect.

Comment: Back in the day, the 4" octagon boxes were called "four-oh" boxes. So, apparently he was talking about LED fixtures that fit into these boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"4O light" or "4/O light" appears to be jargon for a light fixture that can be mounted in a 4/O octagonal junction box.

Comment: Now that you say that, the "oh" is probably an O (for octagonal) and not a a zero. Makes sense. http://www.orbitelectric.com/steel-products/electrical-junction-boxes/4o-boxes.html?mode=list

Comment: @isherwood - Ah, good call.  I'll make that edit.